# TargetInvocationException?

Tags: c#, wpf

Why would the following lines of code cause a `TargetInvocationException` exception?

```
    private Dispatcher dispatcher = null;

    public DownloadManager(Dispatcher dispatcher = null)
    {
        this.dispatcher = dispatcher ?? Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    }
```

When the `DownloadManager` is instantiated in the XAML like:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <c:DownloadManager />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Note that the debugger doesn't specifically highlight any of these lines; all I know is that if I delete them, my program doesn't crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To instantiate an object through XAML, it needs to have a public default constructor. A parameterized constructor with default values is not the same as a default constructor. As such, the XAML parser is dying when trying to instantiate your object. I'd say a TargetInvocationException with a NullReferenceException as the inner is a bit worthless and something more useful could be thrown as the inner.

Finally, FWIW, the XAML editor in VS2010 is telling me that my Type is unusable without a default constructor when I have a constructor defined like yours.

Use two constructors instead (or just a default constructor):

```
public MyViewModel()
    : this( null ) {
}

public MyViewModel( Dispatcher dispatcher = null ) {
    this._dispatcher = dispatcher ?? Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

Comment: Yep... you're quite right. I didn't expect there to be a difference (between a default c'tor and one with default args).

Answer (score 1):

None that I can see directly, however look in the InnerException if there is one, what does it say?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Which means what? `CurrentDispatcher` was not set? But the docs say if that's the case a new one will be created.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion. Can you add a default constructor to the class and see what happens? Like so:

```
public DownloadManager()
{
   this.dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
}
```

I wonder if XAML doesn't like a constructor with parameters with default values.

Comment: Like so? Your sample has an argument ;)